# Уникальность введенных данных

Tags: python, django

Добрый день.

Задание такое: Добавьте проверку на то, что введенное для нового поста название
уникально.

Что и куда нужно добавить? Поиск в интернете не помогает.

Вот сама функция:

```
def create_post(request):
    if not request.user.is_anonymous():
       if request.method == "POST":
           form = {
               'text': request.POST["text"],
               'title': request.POST["title"]
           }
           if form['text'] and form['title']:
                Article.objects.create(text=form['text'],
                                       title=form['title'],
                                       author=request.user)
               article = Article.objects.get(title=form['title'])
               return redirect('get_article', article_id=article.id)
        else:
               form['errors'] = u'Не все поля заполнены'
               return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'form': form})
       else:
            return render(request, 'create_post.html', {})
      else:
           raise Http404
```

upd: да, я пользуюсь приложением, которое использует django;
в качестве базы данных подключена sqlite3;
как я поняла, задание в том, что если название неуникально, то выводить на экран фразу вроде "Такая статья уже есть, попробуйте еще раз";
ссылки из интернета привести не смогу, так как ничего подходящего не нашла; и, если честно, даже не знаю, что может подходить -- это задание из учебной программы и кроме этого там больше ничего не дано

пробовала через get_or_create, но вышла ошибка ( get() returned more than one Article -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {'title': u'1'} )

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Django create if doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8766222/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Уникальность поля лучше организовывать на уровне модели и бд

```
#models.py

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)

#forms.py

class ArticleForm(form.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', ]
```

http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/forms/modelforms.html
http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/models/fields.html#unique